# Cannot add to favourites using flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, logic, bloc, state-management

I have an app that fetches data from an API and lists out all the dog breeds. This process is done using a DogBreedsBloc.
The main.dart of the app -

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => DogBreedsBloc()..add(DogBreedsRequest())),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => FavouritesCubit()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
        theme: MyTheme.lightTheme(context),
        darkTheme: MyTheme.darkTheme(context),
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => HomePage(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now when the user wants to add any of the breeds to the favorites via the HomeDetailPage it should be added to a list using FavouritesCubit.

This is my FavouritesCubit -

```
class FavouritesCubit extends Cubit<FavouritesState> {
  FavouritesCubit() : super(FavouritesInitial());

  void addToFavourites(BreedsModel breed) {
    if (state.favouriteBreeds.contains(breed) == false) {
      state.favouriteBreeds.add(breed);
    }
    emit(FavouritesAdded());
  }

  void removeFromFavourites(BreedsModel breed) {
    if (state.favouriteBreeds.contains(breed)) {
      state.favouriteBreeds.remove(breed);
    }
    emit(FavouritesRemoved());
  }

  get getfavouriteBreeds {
    return state.favouriteBreeds;
  }
}

part of 'favourites_cubit.dart';

@immutable
abstract class FavouritesState {
  final List<BreedsModel> favouriteBreeds = [];
}

class FavouritesInitial extends FavouritesState {}

class FavouritesAdded extends FavouritesState {}

class FavouritesRemoved extends FavouritesState {}
```

The HomeDetailPage -

```
class HomeDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeDetailPage({Key key, this.theBreed}) : super(key: key);

  final BreedsModel theBreed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          theBreed.name,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontFamily: GoogleFonts.poppins().fontFamily,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: theBreed.image.url,
                placeholder: (context, url) =>
                    Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Description(
              theBreed: theBreed,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: BlocBuilder<FavouritesCubit, FavouritesState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if(state is FavouritesAdded) {
              if (state.favouriteBreeds.contains(theBreed)) {
              return Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.red);
            } else {
              return Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined);
            }
            }
            else if (state is FavouritesRemoved) {
              if (state.favouriteBreeds.contains(theBreed)) {
              return Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.red);
            } else {
              return Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined);
            }
            }
            else {
              if (state.favouriteBreeds.contains(theBreed)) {
              return Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.red);
            } else {
              return Icon(Icons.favorite_border_outlined);
            }
            }
            
          },
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          if (BlocProvider.of<FavouritesCubit>(context)
              .getfavouriteBreeds
              .contains(theBreed)) {
            BlocProvider.of<FavouritesCubit>(context)
                .removeFromFavourites(theBreed);

            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: Text("Removed from Favourites"),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            BlocProvider.of<FavouritesCubit>(context).addToFavourites(theBreed);

            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              SnackBar(
                content: Text("Added to Favourites"),
                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now when I click the floating action button to add the dog breed to favourites, there are two problems i encounter -

1. The child of the floating action button which is an icon does not turn a red heart indicating that this breed has been added to favourites.
2. When I go back to the main page and then go to the favourites page the added breed is not displayed in the favourites list. The favourites list should be displayed in the favourites page.

This is my FavouritesPage -

```
class FavouritesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              MainHeader(header: "Favourites", icon: false),
              BlocBuilder<FavouritesCubit, FavouritesState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is FavouritesAdded) {
                    return Expanded(
                        child: MainList(
                      breeds: state.favouriteBreeds,
                      removeButton: true,
                    ));
                  }
                  else if (state is FavouritesRemoved) {
                    return Expanded(
                        child: MainList(
                      breeds: state.favouriteBreeds,
                      removeButton: true,
                    ));
                  }
                  else if (state is FavouritesInitial) {
                    return Expanded(
                        child: MainList(
                      breeds: state.favouriteBreeds,
                      removeButton: true,
                    ));
                  }
                  else {
                    return Expanded(
                        child: MainList(
                      breeds: state.favouriteBreeds,
                      removeButton: true,
                    ));
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the MainList -

```
class MainList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<BreedsModel> breeds;
  final removeButton;

  const MainList({Key key, this.breeds, this.removeButton}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: breeds.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomeDetailPage(theBreed: breeds[index]),
            ),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                child: Text(
                  breeds[index].name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (removeButton)
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.cancel_outlined),
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  iconSize: 27.0,
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (BlocProvider.of<FavouritesCubit>(context).getfavouriteBreeds.contains(breeds[index])) {
                      
                      BlocProvider.of<FavouritesCubit>(context).removeFromFavourites(breeds[index]);

                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                          content: Text("Removed from Favourites"),
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      BlocProvider.of<FavouritesCubit>(context).addToFavourites(breeds[index]);

                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                          content: Text("Added to Favourites"),
                          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

How to fix these two problems using the bloc state management I'm using for the favourites feature of the app?

The Github link to the repo -
[DogApp](https://github.com/soham1sawant/DogApp/tree/bloc)

Comment: you should use equatable in state class and use async await in your cubit class's motheod; I mean your methods' in cubit class would be of type Future

Comment: Isn't async await used for network calls?